# How can add additional Attribute in my JSON response with dynamic value in laravel

Tags: laravel

In my app i have a **Posts** and a **Reacts** table both are connected with relationship.

In App user can react to a post(like or dislike) and for retrieve this i'm using this function :

```
public function feed()
{
    $posts=Post::with('user')
                ->with('reacts')
                ->withCount('comments')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();
    return response()->json(["posts" => $posts]);
}
```

the response is:

[image]

i want to add one more field in Posts Object for **isUserLiked** and if the current authenticated user liked the post then value will be true or false for him something like this:

[image]

i can add a additional field but how can i set the value dynamically for that

this is what i am doing in my Post Model:

```
 protected $appends = ['isUserLiked'];
 public function getIsUserLikedAttribute($id)
 {
    $react=React::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('post_id',$id)->exists();
    return $react;
 }
```

this is returning false because i don't know any way to pass the arguments(Post id).
is there any better way i can get the desired response? Thanks!

Comment: Since that is the post model you can just do `$this->id`

Comment: If you have a relationship between `Post` and `React`, you could simplify that to `$this->react->where("user_id", "=", auth()->user()->id)->exists();`

Comment: lot of thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getIsUserLikedAttribute($id)
 {
    return React::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('post_id',$this->id)->exists();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your user model:

```
public function reacts(){
   return $this->hasMany(React::class);
}

public function scopeReactOnPost($query, $post_id){
   return $this->reacts()->where(function($query) use ($post_id){
      $query->where('post_id',$post_id);
   });
}
```

and in your controller:

```
$user->reactOnPost($post_id)->first();
```

or

```
$user->reactOnPost($post_id)->get()->count();
```

Will let you know if user had any reaction on the specified post.
and for adding this to your json output you can `artisan` make a resource for your post model. [Laravel Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)